# Is it possible to use 'append' or 'cons' to create a make-list function in Scheme that repeats values based on a given size parameter?

Tags: append, scheme, racket, r5rs, cons

Is there an alternative way of writing the `make-list` function in Scheme (R5RS)? I am trying to create a function where the value repeats itself in the list based on the given size.

So my expected output should be:

```
(print 5 5) --> (5 5 5 5 5)
(print Ana 3) --> (Ana Ana Ana)
```

If the parameters are switched, return an empty list
(print 3 Ana) --> '()

I am doing this through recursion with a helper function and wanted to use either 'append' or 'cons'

```
(define print-helper (lambda (value size)
                           (if (null? value) 
                               0 ;size is zero
                               (print-helper (append(+ value 1) (cdr size)))
                               )))

(define print (lambda (value size)
                    (if not(number? value))
                        '() ;return
                        (print-helper value size) 
                        ))
```

Comment: `(print Ana 3)` should be `(print 'Ana 3)`. You need to quote symbols to treat them literally instead of as variables.

Comment: Why is the size zero when the value is null? `(print '() 5)` should return `(() () () () ())`

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to `value`? It's not a number. And `size` is not a list, you can't use `(cdr size)`. It seems like this code was just thrown together randomly, without really thinking about it.

Comment: You picked out pieces of other recursive functions, without considering whether they apply to this case. Did ChatGPT write this?

Comment: You should be checking whether `size` is a number, not `value`.

Answer (score 0):

- The base case of the recursion should check if `size` is 0, not `value`.
- Use `cons` to construct a list step by step
- The recursive call has to be in the argument to `cons` or `append`, not around the call.
- *Subtract* 1 from `size` when recursing, don't add 1.
- You need parentheses around the call to `not`.
- You should check whether `size` is a number, not `value`.

```
(define print-helper
  (lambda (value size)
    (if (<= size 0) 
        '()
        (cons value (print-helper value (- size 1))))))

(define print
  (lambda (value size)
    (if (not (number? size))
        '() ;return
        (print-helper value size))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the recursive solution, R5RS Scheme already provides [`make-vector`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_560) (and then you can use [`vector->list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_idx_570) to get list)- you can use them in your `print`:

```
(define (print item times)
  (vector->list (make-vector times item)))
```

Examples:

```
> (print 5 5)
(5 5 5 5 5)

> (print "Ana" 3)
("Ana" "Ana" "Ana")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are confused about what makes a list. in Scheme a list is a chain of `cons`. `(1 2 4 6)` is just fancy printing of the list `(1 . (2 . (4 . (6 . ())))` or `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 4 (cons 6 '()))))`.

Lists are created from the end to the beginning. The order of execution makes the list `(6)` before it can make `(4 6)` because while order of evaluation on the same level is not given, we know that all arguments are evaluated before application and that means that in `(cons 1 expr)` `expr` is fully evaluated to `(2 3 4 6)`.

So making a list with the same value, you don't really need to worry about order so I'll show you how to make a list like `range` does it:

```
;; unoptimized growing stack way
(define (my-range to)
  (let helper ((from 0))
    (if (>= from to)
        '()
        (cons from 
              (helper (+ 1 from))))))

;; accumulating version with reverse; better
(define (my-range to)
  (let helper ((from 0) (acc '()))
    (if (>= from to)
        (reverse acc)
        (helper (+ 1 from) (cons from acc)))))

;; Best doing it in reverse, the order lists are created
(define (my-range to)
  (let helper ((to (- to 1)) (acc '()))
    (if (< to 0)
        acc
        (helper (- to 1) (cons to acc)))))
                 
;; test
(my-range 10) ; ==> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

THat last one can be changed to take a value and use that instead ot the counting and then you can keep the initial value and rather stop at zero instead of below zero.  Good luck